# How to get selected date from inline datepicker on a servlet

Tags: java, jquery, datepicker

Im trying to get the selected date of an inline jquery datepicker.I need to use selected date in Java code and not in JS.I tried to bind it to a hidden input but it didnt work, i only got `null`.

html:

`<div id='datepicker'></div>
 <input type="hidden" id="datepicker_send" name="datepicker_send"> 
 <div>Free Appointments on <label id="selectedDate">:</label></div>`

and js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#datepicker").datepicker({altField:'#datepicker_send'});

$("#datepicker").on("change",function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
     $('#selectedDate').html(selected);
});
```

I tried

```
request.getParameter("datepicker_send");
```

and i only got `null`. Do you have any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `request.getParameter("selectedDate")`?  Please share a little more of code.  Specifically HTML

Answer (score 0):

In your JS, try: 
`var selected = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');`

instead of: `var selected = $(this).val();`

this will trigger the getDate function in the datepicker class to actually get the date.